# how resize an element without modifying its content. css

Tags: css, resize

I included in my project a new CSS library that included designs for buttons.
I would like to change the height of this button:
[image: button]

but when I use the high css property, the following happens:
[image]
[image]

after line-height propiety:

[image]

code:

```
<button class="btn btn-4 btn-4c icon-arrow-right" ><label>button</label></button>
```

source: [source](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/)

how you could resize?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which high css property have to used ?

Comment: For a 1:1 resize while preserving all proportions, you could use a `transform:scale(0.5)`, althought that might shrink the font too much. If the arrow image is a background-image, adjusting the `background-position` might also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `line-height` property

Eg: `line-height: 0.5`

```
<button class="btn btn-4 btn-4c icon-arrow-right" style="line-height:5" ><label>button</label></button>
```

adjust line-height in this class too.

```
.btn-4:before {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
font-size: 125%;
line-height: 6.5; //Adjust this
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
```

}

Comment: using the property you give me, everything is ok. however, when I hover on the button, the arrow still poorly positioned.

Comment: Give line-height property to both text and arrow

Comment: Check Edited solution
you can inspect arrow element in your browser and then check line-height property in btn-4c:before or .btn-4c:after

Answer (score 1):

here is the animated version :) https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/evedzdbk/1/
your request is the following style code :)

```
#button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
border-radius:5rem;
  background:#2390fd;
  margin:5%;
  position:absolute;
   display:table;
   transition:.5s;
}
span{
 font-size:15px;
  font-weight:600;
 display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

i hope this is useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

We need more details like which **CSS** library are you using or CSS code of all those classes (`btn btn-4 btn-4c icon-arrow-right`) which are used on the button in order to help you out.

Comment: Please, see the source.

Comment: You need to tweak around **line-height**, **padding** of `btn`, `btn-4:before`. **For example :** I have changed the padding of `btn` to `padding: 21px 80px;` and line-height of `btn-4:before` to `line-height:3.1;`